# I have several XML documents that have different amount of names under images on each page

Tags: sqlxml

I have several XML documents that have different amount of names under images on each page. It can be one name or it could be 50. how can I insert this into a SQL database?
This is a snippet of the XML, so under images there is a name is this there are 2, but the next XML could have 10. the info inside of name is the same every time.  How do I insert into SQL when these can be different any or every time?
-

-
1073073r1Prepress_step_CDI-SDDC_DRed_1.len 
49.9429

21.7758

2400.0

1087.549

1

1

51.1929

23.0258

1178.76

"./images/7-17-14_Flat_1_FRC250Conv/1073073r1Prepress_step_CDI-SDDC_DRed_1__.len.gif"

-
1070635r0Prepress_step_CDI-SD_K_1.len 
27.4746

6.7833

2400.0

186.369

1

1

29.6695

8.9782

266.379

"./images/7-17-14_Flat_1_FRC250Conv/1070635r0Prepress_step_CDI-SD_K_1__.len.gif"

Comment: Could you try formatting the xml a little better? If you indent the block of code by four spaces it should retain all of the brackets, etc

Comment: I formatted the data

Answer (score 0):

```
-<Name>
1073073r1Prepress_step_CDI-SDDC_DRed_1.len 
<Width unit="inch">49.9429</Width>

<Height unit="inch">21.7758</Height>

<Resolution unit="DPI">2400.0</Resolution>

<Area unit="sq in">1087.549</Area>

<X-Repeat>1</X-Repeat>

<Y-Repeat>1</Y-Repeat>

<Used_Width unit="inch">51.1929</Used_Width>

<Used_Height unit="inch">23.0258</Used_Height>

<TotalArea unit="sq in">1178.76</TotalArea>

<GIF-IMAGE> "./images/7-17-14_Flat_1_FRC250Conv/1073073r1Prepress_step_CDI-  SDDC_DRed_1__.len.gif" </GIF-IMAGE>

</Name>


-<Name>
1070635r0Prepress_step_CDI-SD_K_1.len 
<Width unit="inch">27.4746</Width>

<Height unit="inch">6.7833</Height>

<Resolution unit="DPI">2400.0</Resolution>

<Area unit="sq in">186.369</Area>

<X-Repeat>1</X-Repeat>

<Y-Repeat>1</Y-Repeat>

<Used_Width unit="inch">29.6695</Used_Width>

<Used_Height unit="inch">8.9782</Used_Height>

<TotalArea unit="sq in">266.379</TotalArea>

<GIF-IMAGE> "./images/7-17-14_Flat_1_FRC250Conv/1070635r0Prepress_step_CDI-SD_K_1__.len.gif"      </GIF-IMAGE>

</Name>
```